# Modifying Font Style simple marker according to character value

Tags: pyqgis, markers, font

Currently I am writing a standalone Python script and I am trying to modify a simple point marker using font style. There are some interesting fonts with different characters that aren't exactly on a normal keyboard. Does anyone know how to use these characters?

For example, I currently have:

```
symbol = QgsMarkerSymbolV2.createSimple({'color': 'transparent', 'outline_color': 'transparent'})
layer.rendererV2().setSymbol(symbol)
# create the fontStyle symbol
fontStyle = {}
fontStyle['color'] = 'gray'
fontStyle['font'] = 'DejaVu Serif'
fontStyle['chr'] = '0x65'
fontStyle['size'] = '8'
# create a layer for the fontStyle
symLyr1 = QgsFontMarkerSymbolLayerV2.create(fontStyle)
symbol.appendSymbolLayer(symLyr1)
```

I can't type in the actual character in fontStyle['chr'] but I do know the actual value pertaining to the desired character. Is there a 'value' property such that I can say something like:

```
fontStyle['value'] = '0x65'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do this:

```
fontStyle['value'] = '\x65'
```

You can read more about the unicode here:
https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Comment: Unfortunately this change doesn't seem to affect my code at all. I still just see a default print of the char 'A' instead of the character I would like to see.

Comment: Have you tried u'\x65'? It works for me, I ve got a snowflake.